# Write array to text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to write a 5x3 array to a text file following an example found here using this code.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('array_float.txt')
with open('out.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for data_slice in data:
        np.savetxt(outfile, data_slice, fmt='%4.1f')
```

It results in the following error:

```
File C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1087, in savetxt
  fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

It seems savetxt doesn't like the outfile object. I'm able to get savetxt to work when I specify the actual outfile name. For example, this works:

```
np.savetxt('out.txt', data_slice, fmt='%4.1f')
```

But only the last line of the array gets save to 'out.txt'.

Answer (score 3):

You should open the file in binary mode (using `ab` or `wb`)

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('array_float.txt')
with open('out.txt', 'ab') as outfile:
    for data_slice in data:
        np.savetxt(outfile, data_slice, fmt='%4.1f')
```

Comment: Thanks, that works but the array is all on one line in the output file. How do I get each line of the array to write to a new line in the output file?

Comment: @DaveLeighton Try `np.savetxt(outfile, data_slice, fmt='%4.1f', newline="\n")` instead

Comment: Yeah, that was the first thing I tried, but it didn't change the output. Still all on one line.

Comment: @RafaelCardoso: For portability to a Windows system with a file opened in binary mode, shouldn't that be something like `newline=os.linesep`? Windows text editors often treat `\n` by itself as plain whitespace or nothing, and only `\r\n` actually gets rendered as a line break. The default is already `\n` after all, so `newline="\n"` doesn't change behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use Python's pickle module.  It allows the saving of any array with very few complications or lines of code.

Try this:

```
import pickle
f = open(name_of_file,'w')
pickle.dump(f,name_of_array)
f.close()
```